# Filter does not execute when 404 occur, symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4

I wrote custom filter and it is working just fine. For test i putted custom HTTP header in response. But when 404 page occur i can't see my custom HTTP header.

So my question is: am i doing something wrong or this is normal and usual in other frameworks ?

Comment: You would have to check how Symfony creates the 404 response, but my guess is that it resets all response headers.

Comment: Symfony stops execution of filters when 404 occur, i checked. I even tried to hook on various response events, without success. My solution in this case was to override sfWebResponse class and put my code before parent::send() method in send method of response class.

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem add it as an answer and accept it. It might help some people in the future who will get stuck on a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to extend sfWebResponse class and override send() method like this:

```
class MyWebResponse extends sfWebResponse {

    public function send() {  
      //custom code
      parent::send();
    }

}
```